# How to ensure that empty values are included in @FormParam with type list

Tags: jax-rs, form-parameter

I have several input tags like this

```
<input placeholder="someValue" name="someInputs"/>
```

All share the same name.

In an command object, I have this field

```
@FormParam("someInputs")
private List<String> someInputs;
```

If some of the fields are not provided by the user, those will not included as empty strings in  the list. Is it possible to configure, that empty fields will be included in the list as empty strings ?
I need to ensure that the list has the same size, like input fields are provided in html.

Comment: Could you tell us if the actual HTTP request sent contains all values or if the browser strips empty ones?

Comment: Here's a hacky idea. Pre-populate the fields with a single space character, so that the browser is forced to return the field, then strip out the white space in the jax-rs method